# BibTeX styles other than unsrt with pmcid

Tags: bibtex

I seek a bibtex style that displays NIH Pubmed PMCID fields but sorts the bibliography.  The only .bst file I have seen that displays PMCID is nihunsrt.bst. Are there other .bst files based on other standard styles?